# Mysqli - When opening 2 connections to the same host with mysql, but different databases, does mysqli open the connection once?

Tags: php, mysqli

When I have a situation like this:

```
$databaseA = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,"databaseA");
$databaseB = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,"databaseB");
```

When I define `$databaseB`, does mysqli try to re-open the connection to `$host`, or does it use the cached connection from `$databaseA`?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you have a good reason to use two different databases, the only way to make this work with a single connection is with a user that has privileges to access both databases. It would go something like this:

```
$db = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass); // connect to the MySQL server without specifying a database

mysqli_select_db('databaseA', $db); // Specify your default/most-used database
```

If you don't explicitly specify databaseB in your query, MySQL will use the default (databaseA). So a query that gets one column from databaseB and two from databaseA would look like this:

```
$query = "SELECT databaseB.table.column, table.column, table.column2";
```

Comment: I'm going for that! Thanks.

Comment: I would want to do something more like $this->db->database_one->query("UPDATE mytable SET..."); $this->db->database_two->query("UPDATE myothertable SET..."); How could you run an UPDATE or INSERT query on the example of your SELECT? You can't choose the db or the table columns. And even doing the select table.column, that would take a long time for every query to do, I usually use a wild "*" select * from.

Comment: @Idealcastle euhm "UPDATE database_one.mytable SET...", "UPDATE database_two.myothertable SET...". c'est tout! ;]

...and "SELECT * FROM databaseB.yetanothertable". You can even JOIN tables from different databases, should you desire to do so.

Comment: `mysqli_select_db('databaseA', $db);` should be 
`mysqli_select_db($db,'databaseA');`.

Answer (score 3):

For every mysqli-object there will be a separate connection.

Try a

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

on your MySQL server during runtime, you'll see two different processes connected from the same host if your example is implemented.

Comment: Isn't there a way to let mysqli use only one connection for the same host? I mean, when I try to make the second connection, it automatically invoke a function like `mysqli::select_db()`

Comment: Why do you use two connections in the first place? And is this really a problem? I've your connecting to one and the same DB server, one should suffice.