# Connect to Multiple Databases in same/one connection

Tags: php, mysql

How could this be done within PHP. without reloading or adding an entire new connection. 
MySQL has one connection, that gives you access to multiple databases.

Where you could call,

```
$this->db = my_database_connection;
$this->db->database_one->query();
$this->db->database_two->query();
```

and when those run, it understands which database it needs to utilize without creating a new db connection.

Is this even possible?

I have an application I want to run queries and data from multiple databases (with a heavy load of traffic) but I don't want to have it use 2 connections per user, seems inefficient. The databases have the same credentials for the connection (host,pass,user) but I have many database within that connection.

Comment: You should be able to use `USE database_two` right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysqli - When opening 2 connections to the same host with mysql, but different databases, does mysqli open the connection once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758760/mysqli-when-opening-2-connections-to-the-same-host-with-mysql-but-different-d)