# PHP SQL : How to save data to multiple database from one html form OR how to copy data from one database to another database automatically

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a html form, say example

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and form.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "database1";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "database1";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//escape variables for security
$fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fname']);
$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lname']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (fname,lname)
VALUES ('$fname','$lname')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   echo "Successfully Saved";

    } else {
    echo "Error: Go back and Try Again ! " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

The form.php is saving that data to `database1` .

I want that data to be saved to another database `database2` along with `database1`.

Is it possible ?? If yes then what changes should be made in the code ?

If it is not possible then is it possible to copy data from `database1` to `database2` automatically? Whenever a new row is added in `database1` then it should automatically copied to `database2`.

I want the same data to be in two different database. How can I achieve any of the above said ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From php you just have to create new connection to DB.

```
<?php
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "database1";
   $password = "xxxxxxxx";
   $dbname = "database1";


   $servernameS = "localhost";
   $usernameS = "database2";
   $passwordS = "xxxxxxxx";
   $dbnameS = "database2";

   // Create connection
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   $connS = new mysqli($servernameS, $usernameS, $passwordS, $dbnameS);

   // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }
   if ($connS->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $connS->connect_error);
   }

   //escape variables for security
   $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fname']);
   $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lname']);

   $sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (fname,lname) 
   VALUES ('$fname','$lname')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "Successfully Saved";

    } else {
      echo "Error: Go back and Try Again ! " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    if ($connS->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "Successfully Saved";

    } else {
      echo "Error: Go back and Try Again ! " . $sql . "<br>" . $connS->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
    $connS->close();

   ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

What it sounds like you need is to setup replication.

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html) is the official documentation on replication. [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql) is a simpler step-by-step guide setting it up.

If replication isn't what you wanted, you could accomplish the same thing by connecting to database2 in addition to database1 then running the query once on both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like using [mysqli::selectDB method](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* return name of current default database */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    $result->close();
}

/* change db to world db */
$mysqli->select_db("world");

/* return name of current default database */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Check out the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php).

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27767526/3402095) as yours at SO.