# PHP SQL : How to display Unique ID to which data is saved just now?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, echo, unique-id

Please read this question for clear understanding

[PHP SQL : How to save data to multiple database from one html form OR how to copy data from one database to another database automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542349/php-sql-how-to-save-data-to-multiple-database-from-one-html-form-or-how-to-cop)

As `form.php` is saving data to 2 different database table. In both the database the `SNo` is the Unique Column and is auto incremented. 
Everytime `SNo` is incremented and data is saved in that row. For a single data, `SNo` remains same in both the database table.

When data is saved successfully, `form.php` echo

> Successfully Saved

I want to echo the `SNo` to which `form.php` just saved the data from any one of the database as `SNo` is same in both the database, as a reference number.

The message should be like this

> Successfully Saved. You Reference No is ??  `//What should be the code at ??`

What should be the code for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
    mysqli_insert_id($conn)
```

to retrieve last auto generated id.

```
echo "Successfully Saved. You Reference No is".mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

Comment: But for example if  5 person submitted that form at same time. Then for the first person the Reference number will be 1, for the second the Reference number will be 2, but since all the 5 person has submitted that form at the same time then till the form echo 1 to first person as the reference no, the SNo would have been incremented to 5. So all the 5 will get the last auto generated ID as 5 as their Reference No!

Comment: That's the main reason for using the link identifier or an object context.  So the id returned is correlated with that connection.

Comment: @Devon : So how to do that ? Please don't give me the link to read. I am very new to it and information on php.net is very confusing to me. Also I need all these php script urgently. So for current I don't want to read, I want answer !

Comment: 5 person from 5 computers at the same time? don't worry about that, you will get the id you want, you wont get other computer's last inserted ID. This function is tied to current db connection

Comment: @Eng Cy: Okay let me try !

Comment: @IrfanAlam The link identifier in your other question is `$conn`, so you'd specify `mysqli_insert_id($conn)`.  If the information at php.net is very confusing, then you probably haven't taken enough time to learn programming the right way.   Rushing into developing code for public sites is dangerous, your bound to overlook things, especially when it comes to security.

Comment: @Devon: Thank you very much for your kind warning. I will surely keep this in my mind. But for the current I need some SQL PHP function to implement on a site. For that I have some questions which I will ask on StackOverflow in within an hour. Once my work will be done then I will start learning programming from the beginning. I am a student and in my syllabus all these programming language will come after 1 or 2 year. But I want to do something extra now only, thats why I am doing this... searching on google, asking on stackoverflow... :p

Answer (score 0):

Or since you didn't specify an SQL API, for PDO:

`$pdo->lastInsertId()`

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php