# How to check two databases for same query and display the result, in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Please read [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542349/php-sql-how-to-save-data-to-multiple-database-from-one-html-form-or-how-to-cop) for clear understanding.

As `form.php` is saving data to two different database table. In both the database the `SNo` is the Unique Column and is auto incremented. Everytime `SNo` is incremented and data is saved in that row. For a single data, `SNo` remains same in both the database table.

I have added some more column in both the database. Now the database looks like

```
SNo   |  fname   |  lname  |    mobile    |    Request    |   status  |

1     |  John    |  Alto   |  9999999999  |   Send M1     |  Not Sent |   
2     |  khan    |  asif   |  8888888888  |   Send D1     |  Not Sent |
3     |  John    |  Alto   |  9999999999  |   Send M2     |  Not Sent |   
4     |  khan    |  asif   |  8888888888  |   Send D2     |  Not Sent |
5     |  John    |  Alto   |  9999999999  |   Send M3     |  Not Sent |   
6     |  khan    |  asif   |  8888888888  |   Send D3     |  Not Sent |
7     |  Kerr    |  Lync   |  7878787878  |   Send F3     |  Not Sent |   
8     |  Sara    |  goda   |  8585858585  |   Send L2     |  Not Sent |
```

Since `form.php` is saving data from the form to two different database. The data will be available exactly the same on both the database table. Let the table name on both the database is `mytable`

I have created a html form to check status, check.html

```
<form action="status.php" method="get">
Enter SNo : <input type="text" name="SNo"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and the status.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "db";
$password = "123123";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$SNo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['SNo']);

$sql = "SELECT * from mytable
    WHERE SNo = '$SNo'";



$result = $conn->query($sql);
$columns = array();
$resultset = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (empty($columns)) {
        $columns = array_keys($row);
    }
    $resultset[] = $row;
}

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<thead><tr><th>SNo</th><th>First Name</th><th>USN</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Mobile</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>{$row['SNo']}</td><td>{$row['fname']}</td><td>{$row['lname']}</td><td>{$row['mobile']}</td><td>{$row['Request']}</td></tr></tbody>";
echo " Delivered or Not Delivered" // What should be code here ?

// Print the data
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    foreach($row as $_column) {
        echo "{$_column}";
    }
}
    }
} else {
    echo "SNo Not Found";

}
$conn->close();

?>
```

I want the `SNo` should be first checked in `db1`, if it is NOT present there then echo " Not Found ". If it is there in `db1` then it should be checked again in `db2`, if it also in `db2` then echo " Not Delivered ". If it is in `db1` but not in `db2` then echo " Delivered".
What changes should be made in status.php code to perform such action ?

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` does not mix with `mysqli_` functions. Nor does `mysql_fetch_row` or any other function starting with `mysql_`.

Comment: Hi Irfan. The community has at length discussed the practice of home-made tagging in titles (i.e. "PHP SQL: [title]") and decided that we prefer titles without this - it is better to just formulate them as questions in ordinary English. The discussions are on _Meta_ if you'd be interested to read them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code could use some optimization, which I'll do as I double-check this response, but this should do what you want. I've removed what seems to be few extraneous loops.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "db";
$password = "123123";
$db1Name = "db";

$servername2 = "localhost";
$username2 = "db2";
$password2 = "1231232";
$db2Name = "db2";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db1Name);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$SNo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['SNo']);

$sql = "SELECT * from mytable
    WHERE SNo = '$SNo'";

$db1Result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($db1Result->num_rows > 0) {     // If data found in db1 ...

    // Echo the data from db1    
    while($row = $db1Result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<thead><tr><th>SNo</th><th>First Name</th><th>USN</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Mobile</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>{$row['SNo']}</td><td>{$row['fname']}</td><td>{$row['lname']}</td><td>{$row['mobile']}</td><td>{$row['Request']}</td></tr></tbody>";


        // Now, check if it's present in db2
        $conn2 = new mysqli($servername2, $username2, $password2, $db2Name);
        $db2Result = $conn2->query($sql);

        if ($db2Result->num_rows > 0) { // If data is found in db2...
            echo "Not delivered";
        } else { // If data is NOT in db2...
            echo "Delivered";
        }
    }
} else { // If data is NOT found in db1...
    echo "SNo Not Found";

}
$conn->close();

?>
```

It's good practice to comment frequently when you're dealing with confusing logic like this--it will help keep your sanity. :) It's also a good idea not to use the `*` in your `SELECT` statement; instead, specify only the names of the columns that you need.

As a more general point, I'm not sure why you were attempting to loop through the resultset three times in your original code--I assume you were trying to diagnose a problem--and moreover, using both the `mysqli` and `mysql` API's together **will not work**; you should only be using `mysqli` functions, and there's no need to loop through the MySQL results more than one time here. The resource you attempt to pass to `mysql_fetch_row()` is not even of the right type, so that call is doomed to failure.

Comment: Problematic? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I clearly have a penchant for understatement. Edited for forcefulness. :)

Comment: Both the database has different user and different password. I am very new to it, so may be I do not understood it completely. From the above code what can I see that connection is made only to db1 and not to db2. So in this situation will the code work?

Comment: Edited for additional forcefulness ;-)

Comment: @IrfanAlam You'll just need to create another connection, then, and use that for the second query instead of reusing `$conn`. Something like `$conn2 = new mysqli(...)` etc.

Comment: Make sure you're using the most recent code I posted. It's not causing a 500 error for me. Are you able to check your server logs?